# Additional MVC Route with Optional Parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to add a custom route, but I can't get it to work.
I want to use normal routing, except when it hits a specific controller,to use a different optional parameter instead of id.

In my area, this exists:

```
context.MapRoute(
     "Admin_default",
     "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );
```

and above that I tried to add:

```
context.MapRoute(
           "Admin_Users",
           "Admin/Users/{action}/{username}",
           new { action = "Index", username = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
```

And in code, I call the page with:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { username=user.UserName })
```

and it works, but the link shows up as **/Admin/Users/Edit/?username**

and I want: **/Admin/Users/Edit/username**

However, I want to keep the same route for all my other pages, that being:

```
/Admin/Shop/Products/Edit/1
```

which uses the default routing

**EDIT**

I got it to work by adding in controller="Users", in my route.

```
context.MapRoute(
       "Admin_Users",
       "Admin/Users/{action}/{username}",
       new { controller="Users", action = "Index", username = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
```

I thought this was the point of the URL part (the line above) of it?

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: Dont worry, i used the aspnet.mvc tag. Any advice on the question?

Comment: ... actually i used the tag , if you look in the edit history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is correct, but your order is not.

ASP.NET MVC uses the **first** route that applies. In your case, the generic route will apply. Change the order and your 'Admin/User/...' route will have higher precedence.

Comment: I think that's the problem.  It didn't work above or below, but I think it's because the default route works for everything under Admin/Users also.